# SAS ARIMA forecast estimate statement

Tags: arima, sas

Im trying to forecast a timeseries (daily intervals) but I am unsure of the syntax of the estimate statement. I know `p` is for autoregression and `q` is for moving averages, but what do the (2)(12) and (1 3) mean, and what values should they be if the `interval = day`?

```
proc arima data=daily;
 i var=SUM_of_Total_Revenue2;
run;
e p=(2)(12) q=(1 3);
 f lead=365
    out=daily2
    id=Order_date
    interval=day
    noprint;
```

Comment: Be aware the questions about code are generally off-topic here. This one is borderline, IMO, as there is a statistical question behind the code. It would help however, if you could make the *statistical* aspect of your Q more prominent. It might also help (ironically) if you could provide the full code, eg what PROC is that?

Comment: I meant what proc is the `e... noprint;` in? AFAIK, you couldn't run that code in SAS on its own.

Comment: I have been involved several daily forecasting tasks, but I have not come across any model like yours, can you please post the series ? its strange to have a seasonality of 12 for a daily forecasting its usually 7 or 365.

Comment: I think it shoul be 365 instead of 12. here is the series.http://imgur.com/G0sUM8d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SAS` has extensive documentation on all their procedures. Please see [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_arima_sect022.htm) for the syntax for `PROC ARIMA`.

As you noted `p` is for autoregressive and `q` is for moving average in an arima model. In `proc arima` if `p` or `q` is separated by a bracket then it means that there is a seasonal autoregressive model.For your example, what p = (2)(12) means is that current day of SUM_of_Total_Revenue2 is related to 2 days (nonseasonal ar) before and also related to 12 days (seasonal ar) before the current day.

Mathematically using back-shift notation this could be represented as follows. I'm following the notation used in [Makridakis et al](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471532339):

$(1-\phi_1B^2)(1-\Phi_1B^{12}) Y_t = (1-\theta_1B-\theta_1B^3)e_t$

Left hand is non seasonal and seasonal `ar(p)` and right hand side is the nonseasonal `ma(q)`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

My experience tells me that the analysis of daily data would never lead to the ARIMA model that you propose. How did you go about identifying such a model for daily data (7 days in a week) ?  Are you analysing daily data that has 6 readings per week ? A more appropriate model might include daily fixed effects, weekly or monthly effects , holiday effects and perhaps an ARIMA structure or order 1 or 7 or perhaps 6 if the data is 6 periods per week . Care should be taken to deal with and identify and incorporate pulses, level shifts and perhaps trends.